# Why is my nested object returning undefined when looping through?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

https://plnkr.co/edit/aZi06HM9CkM9lScy9LS3?p=preview

```
$scope.lettersandthings = [
   { letter: "a", things: [{name:"airplane"}, {name:"apple"}, {name:"alligator"}]}, 
   { letter: "b", things: [{name:"bath"}, {name:"bicycle"}, {name:"bear"}]},
   { letter: "c", things: [{name:"chair"}, {name:"carrot"}, {name:"cat"}]}
 ];
```

---

```
$scope.allchildrenLength = 9;
$scope.allparentsLength = 3;
```

---

```
ng-click="myFunction(0)" <!-- indexParent -->
ng-click="myFunction(1)"
ng-click="myFunction(2)"
```

---

```
for(i=0; i < $scope.allchildrenLength; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < $scope.allparentsLength; j++)  {
      $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open = !$scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open || $scope.lettersandthings[j].open ? false : $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open;
    }
  }
```

This section of `myFunction()` is giving me the errors (however it is still functioning as it should):

- TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
- TypeError: Cannot set property 'open' of undefined

I've read that you need to use a 'for...in' loop for accessing nested objects but i'm not sure exactly how to do this for my case. I tried here but i'm still getting the same errors (and it stopped functioning):

```
for(var lttr in $scope.lettersandthings) {
    for(var thng in $scope.lettersandthings[lttr]) {
      $scope.lettersandthings[lttr].things[thng].open = !$scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open || $scope.lettersandthings[lttr].open ? false : $scope.lettersandthings[lttr].things[thng].open;
    }
  }
```

Even though it's working as it should I'd like to be error-free. Thank you.

**Full code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <style type="text/css">
      .section {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

     
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
            <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
              <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
                {{heading}}
              </span>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
          <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
        </div>
      </script>

      <div class="section">
        <button ng-click="myFunction(0)">Toggle a</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[0].things[0].open = !lettersandthings[0].things[0].open">Toggle airplane</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[0].things[1].open = !lettersandthings[0].things[1].open">Toggle apple</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[0].things[2].open = !lettersandthings[0].things[2].open">Toggle alligator</button>
      </div>

      <div class="section">
        <button ng-click="myFunction(1)">Toggle b</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[1].things[0].open = !lettersandthings[1].things[0].open">Toggle bath</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[1].things[1].open = !lettersandthings[1].things[1].open">Toggle bicycle</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[1].things[2].open = !lettersandthings[1].things[2].open">Toggle bear</button>
       </div>

      <div class="section">
        <button ng-click="myFunction(2)">Toggle c</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[2].things[0].open = !lettersandthings[2].things[0].open">Toggle chair</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[2].things[1].open = !lettersandthings[2].things[1].open">Toggle carrot</button>
          <button ng-click="lettersandthings[2].things[2].open = !lettersandthings[2].things[2].open">Toggle cat</button>
      </div>


    <div id="accordion-wrapper">

      <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
          <div uib-accordion-group  id="accordion" ng-repeat="l in lettersandthings" heading="{{l.letter}}" class="eachLetter" id="{{l.id}}" is-open="l.open">

            <!-- nested accordion -->
            <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
              <div uib-accordion-group id="inner-accordion" class="innercontent" ng-repeat="thing in l.things" heading="{{thing.name}}" is-open="thing.open">
                <p>{{thing.name}} content</p>
              </div>  
            </uib-accordion>

          </div>
      </uib-accordion>  

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

  myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.allchildrenLength = 9;
    $scope.allparentsLength = 3;

    $scope.myFunction = function(indexParent) {

    // First close the outer tab
    $scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open = !$scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open;

      // Close all inner tabs if the outer parent is closed or any other tab is opened
      for(i=0; i < $scope.allchildrenLength; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j < $scope.allparentsLength; j++)  {
          $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open = !$scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open || $scope.lettersandthings[j].open ? false : $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open;
        }
      }
      
    }
  

    $scope.lettersandthings = [
       { letter: "a", things: [{name:"airplane"}, {name:"apple"}, {name:"alligator"}]}, 
       { letter: "b", things: [{name:"bath"}, {name:"bicycle"}, {name:"bear"}]},
       { letter: "c", things: [{name:"chair"}, {name:"carrot"}, {name:"cat"}]}
     ];    

  });

</script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're looping `j` from `0` to `< $scope.allparentsLength`, but then indexing into `$scope.lettersandthings`. To correctly loop through with a `for` loop, make the condition `j < `$scope.lettersandthings.length`. My guess is at some point, `$scope.lettersandthings.length` isn't the same as `$scope.allparentsLength`.

Comment: Re your plunker: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll bear this in mind in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing for instance `things[3]` but eventhough you have 9 things in total, each of your `things` arrays is only 3 elements long so the fourth element (and all after that up to the 9th) are `undefined`

You should switch the inner and outer loop and check the length of each `things` array before iterating

```
for(j=0; j < $scope.allparentsLength; j++) { 
  for(i=0; i< $scope.lettersandthings[j]. things.length; i++) { 
    $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open = !$scope.lettersandthings[indexParent].open || $scope.lettersandthings[j].open ? false : $scope.lettersandthings[j].things[i].open; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This is the answer I was looking for.